# For loops hangs when trying to use various previous row values in calculating a new column. Need to find a non-for loop solution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset of 6.5 million rows in which each user ID's interaction with a token supplier are recorded.
The data is sorted by 'id' and 'Days'
The 'Days' column is the count of days since they joined the supplier.

The day on which a user is given tokens, it is mentioned in column `token_SUPPLY`.
Each day one token is used.

I want to create a column in which the number of available tokens for every row is mentioned.

The logic I've used is:
For each row check if we are still looking at the same user 'id'. If yes then check if any tokens have been supplied, if yes, then save the day number.
For each subsequent row of the same user, calculate available tokens the number of tokens supplied minus the number of days passed since the tokens were supplied.

```
currID=0
tokenSupply=0
giveDay=0
for row in df11.itertuples():
    if row.id != currID:
        tokenSupply = 0
        currID= row.id
    if row.token_SUPPLY > 0:
        giveDay=row.Days
        tokenSupply = row.token_SUPPLY
        df11.loc[row.Index,"token_onhand"]=tokenSupply
    else:
        if tokenSupply == 0:
            df11.loc[row.Index,"token_onhand"]=0
        else:
            df11.loc[row.Index,"token_onhand"]=tokenSupply-(row.Days-giveDay)

# For loop doesn't end for more than 50 minutes.
```

I've been reading a lot since last night and it seems that people have suggested using `numpy`, but I don't know how to do that as I'm just learning to use these things. The other suggestion was to `@jit`, but I guess that works only if I define a function.

Another suggestion was to vectorise, but how would I then access rows conditionally and remember the the supplied quantity to use in every subsequent row ?
I did try using `np.where` but it seemed to get too convoluted to wrap my around around it.

I also ready somewhere about `Cython`, but again, I have no idea how to do that properly.

What would be the best approach to achieve my objective ?

EDIT: Added sample data and required output column

Sample output data:

```
    id      Days  token_SUPPLY            give_event     token_onhand
190 ID1001  -12    NaN                         0           0.0
191 ID1001  -12    NaN                         0           0.0
192 ID1001  -3     NaN                         0           0.0
193 ID1001  0      5.0                         0           5.0
194 ID1001  0      5.0                         1           5.0
195 ID1001  6      NaN                         0          -1.0
196 ID1001  12     NaN                         0          -7.0
197 ID1001  12     NaN                         0          -7.0
198 ID1001  13     NaN                         0          -8.0
199 ID1001  13     NaN                         0          -8.0
```

The last column `token_onhand` is not in the dataset, and is what actually needs to be generated.

Comment: that's because you're using for loops which pandas doesn't handle very well, you need to use vectorised solutions to take advantage of the underlying code which is written in C/Cython. To that end, can you post a sample of your data set and a sample of your output? we will be able to present a more optimal solution hopefully.

Comment: @Datanovice Added sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

Sample Data:

```
       id  Days  token_SUPPLY  give_event
0   ID1001   -12           NaN           0
1   ID1001   -12           NaN           0
2   ID1001    -3           NaN           0
3   ID1001     0           5.0           0
4   ID1001     0           5.0           1
5   ID1001     6           NaN           0
6   ID1001    12           NaN           0
7   ID1001    12           NaN           0
8   ID1001    13           NaN           0
9   ID1001    13           NaN           0
10  ID1002   -12           NaN           0
11  ID1002   -12           NaN           0
12  ID1002    -3           NaN           0
13  ID1002     0           5.0           0
14  ID1002     0           5.0           1
15  ID1002     6           NaN           0
16  ID1002    12           NaN           0
17  ID1002    12           NaN           0
18  ID1002    13           NaN           0
19  ID1002    13           NaN           0
```

You can use`ffill` on `token_Supply` and subtract `Days`.  For more than on `id` use `groupby`.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['token_onhand'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: (x['token_SUPPLY'].ffill() - x['Days']).fillna(0)).reset_index(drop=True)

df
```

Result:

```
        id  Days  token_SUPPLY  give_event  token_onhand
0   ID1001   -12           NaN           0           0.0
1   ID1001   -12           NaN           0           0.0
2   ID1001    -3           NaN           0           0.0
3   ID1001     0           5.0           0           5.0
4   ID1001     0           5.0           1           5.0
5   ID1001     6           NaN           0          -1.0
6   ID1001    12           NaN           0          -7.0
7   ID1001    12           NaN           0          -7.0
8   ID1001    13           NaN           0          -8.0
9   ID1001    13           NaN           0          -8.0
10  ID1002   -12           NaN           0           0.0
11  ID1002   -12           NaN           0           0.0
12  ID1002    -3           NaN           0           0.0
13  ID1002     0           5.0           0           5.0
14  ID1002     0           5.0           1           5.0
15  ID1002     6           NaN           0          -1.0
16  ID1002    12           NaN           0          -7.0
17  ID1002    12           NaN           0          -7.0
18  ID1002    13           NaN           0          -8.0
19  ID1002    13           NaN           0          -8.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty elegant. However, this doesn't seem to work if tokens are supplied on any day other than day 0. They could get tokens again on day 20 or may have had tokens from day -20.

Comment: Hey @michael gardner , just checking in to see if you have an answer based on my clarification.